# Ramsey number conjectures?

Tags: co.combinatorics, ramsey-theory

It's well known that  R(r, s) ≤ R(r − 1, s) + R(r, s − 1).

I believe that there should  be some formulas between these three numbers above and R(r - 1, s - 1).
After observing the latest datas carefully in  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem,

**Conjecture 1:**   R(r - 1, s) + R(r, s - 1)  <  R(r, s) + R(r - 1, s - 1)

**Conjecture 2:**   R(r - 1, s) + R(r, s - 1) ≤  2  *  [  R(r, s) - R(r - 1, s - 1) ]

```
              If it's true, then 43 ≤ R(5,5) .
```

**Conjecture 3:**  R(r, s - 1) <  R(r, s) - R(r - 1, s - 1)  <   R(r - 1, s),   if r > s > 3.

**Conjecture 4:**:  R(r, r) ≤  R(r - 1, r - 1) + R(r - 1, r),  if r > 4.

```
              If it is true, then R(5,5) = 43.
```

Except conjecture 1, all others can give a good boundary for R(r, s).

I tried hard to prove one of them, but failed.

It seems that conjecture 1 and 2 have some sense, but conjecture 3 and 4 are short of solid background.

Could you solve any one?

Comment: Let me point out that an interesting aspect of this question is: 'how refutable' are these conjectures? (Remember that no one knows how to compute Ramsey numbers exactly.) Can one say 'how refutable' these are *without refuting them*? (This I find the most interesting 'qualitative' aspect of this question.) Do these inequalities 'collapse into meaninglessness' if we substitute the usual approximations? Another way to put it: can one 'draw-conclusions-from'/'amplify' the conjectures such that the conclusions get anywhere near to having 'contact' with the usual approximations for Ramsey numbers?